# Can't DropTopology due to event trigger

Tags: postgis, postgresql, topology

I have a PostgreSQL database with one table for each US state. I am trying to make a program which iterates through each of the tables and manipulates the geometry. To do this, at the beginning of the loop I am creating a topology with the line

`SELECT topology.CreateTopology('state_topo', find_srid('schema', 'stateTable', ''geom''));`

Since I'm iterating I want to delete the topology before restarting, so I've included the line:

`SELECT topology.DropTopology(''state_topo'');`

The program works fine with just one state table, however when there are multiple I get the following error:

`ERROR:  cannot DROP TABLE "edge_data" because it has pending trigger events CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP SCHEMA state_topo CASCADE"`

How do I fix this bug?

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the source code of topology.createtopology function to solve this problem. Click the following url to get the solution: https://github.com/panchengwang/sqlcarto/blob/master/postgis_ext.sql

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).